# Web page icons: not resized proportionally

Tags: browser, resize, icons, html

For an icon with different width and height,
Chrome and Firefox resize the icon image to be a square(same width and height), and as a result it is not proportional. Microsoft Edge does a great job here resizing the icon proportionally.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Example Application</title>

     <link rel="icon" href="/images/logo.png">
     <!--   or
     <link rel="icon" sizes="300,200" href="/images/logo.png"> -->
   </head>
   <body>
   Hello, Great day!

   </body>
</html>
```

The icon is shown in page title. Is there a way to tell browser to resize icon proportionally? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS to keep images proportionate. The link sizes attribute is poorly supported in modern browsers:

```
{ height:auto; max-width:100% }
```